# TypeScript: Why is an object literal a valid return value where a class instance is expected?

Tags: typescript

Given this TypeScript code, why is an object literal in the static create method a valid return value where a class instance is expected? At runtime the object literal will obviously fail the instanceof check.

Wouldn't have been the expected behaviour for classes imo (for Interfaces sure). It only would start complaining when a method is on the Greeter class.

[image: TypeScript code]

Comment: JavaScript class instances are objects. JavaScript does a lot of duck-typing.

Comment: Hope the duplicate answers it, if not let me know an I can provide more information.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks for pointing to the duplicate. Well, I do understand the concept and that it is indeed beneficial but I would have expected this behaviour from interfaces only where the instanceof operator doesn't work anyway and not from classes. So the reason why this compiles for classes is still not clear to me but only MS could answer that I guess. I'd love to have a compiler switch for that

Comment: @cmart You can add a private field, that will prevent anything else from being compatible. Structural typing goes all the way, this is what models the JS run time type system best, that is the reason for this behavior. It's just a bit surprising at times.

Comment: I think them major issue is that there's no way to know whether an object was made via `new Class` or by manually creating an object and making it look exactly as it would had it been created via `new Class` (which is absolutely possible). Since you can't differentiate the two then you kind of have to duck-type.

Comment: @apokryfos of course you can. Prototypal inheritance can do this and the instanceof operator does exactly that. Checking wether an instance is an instance of a class or not.

Comment: @cmart you can set the prototype manually though.

Comment: @apokryfos yes but that's not what typescript is supposed to be imo

Comment: A very conscious decision was made with the creation of TypeScript that it is a JavaScript superset and therefore JavaScript code should also be valid TypeScript. This puts TypeScript in this kind of predicament