# Why does TypeScript allow a method to return an object literal when the same value is not assignable to the return type elsewhere?

Tags: typescript

I recently wrote some TypeScript code of the following form, which had a bug in it:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

class MyClass {
  readonly a: string;
  readonly b: string;

  constructor(i: MyInterface) {
    this.a = i.a;
    this.b = i.b;
  }

  myFunc(): string {
    return this.a + ' ' + this.b;
  }

  myNew(): MyClass {
    // Bug (but compiles fine):
    return { ...this, a: 'another a' };
    // What was intended:
    //return new MyClass({ ...this, a: 'another a' });
  }
}
```

There is a bug in the `myNew` method. What I meant to do here was call the constructor to return a new instance of `MyClass`, but instead I returned an object literal. The compiler accepts this, presumably because the object literal has fields matching the `MyClass` fields.

But when you try to call `MyClass` methods on values returned by `myNew()`, they do not exist. The following code compiles but raises an error at runtime:

```js
let c1 = new MyClass({a: 'my a', b: 'my b'});
console.log(c1.myFunc()); // prints "my a my b"

let c2: MyClass = c1.myNew();
// Uncaught TypeError: c2.myFunc is not a function
console.log(c2.myFunc());
```

Someone already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56540555/typescript-why-is-an-object-literal-a-valid-return-value-where-a-class-instance), which is almost the same issue as this. However that question was marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829743/why-duck-typing-is-allowed-for-classes-in-typescript), implying that the fact this code compiles is simply a result of TypeScript's structural typing.

However, the above code demonstrates that the value returned by my buggy code is *not* actually structurally equivalent to a genuine value of `MyClass`, because it is missing the methods declared by that class.

What I find very weird is that when you write the exact equivalent of this code *outside* the class, the compiler correctly detects the error and refuses to compile it:

```js
// Does not compile:
// Type '{ a: string; b: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'MyClass': myFunc, myNew(2739)
let c3: MyClass = { ...c1, a: 'another a' };

// Also does not compile (same error)
let c4: MyClass = { ...c1 };
```

So the type checking that happens *inside* the class seems to be weaker than what happens *outside* it.

Why is this? It feels like a bug to me, but I've been surprised by intentional behaviours of TypeScript's type checking in the past. If it's the result of a deliberate design choice in TypeScript, is there at least some compiler option or ESLint rule I can use that will detect this type of mistake?

I searched various places such as [the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ), the [classes documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) and the [type compatibility documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) but could not find any reference to this phenomenon. The closest I found was [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23363), but that was duped against [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13148) and I don't immediately see the relevance.

[Here is a Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZZOALmQGcwpQBzAblPICNq6GQXSBfUqQQAbODRpp0AYTETCbZFAhwAJgHsQI9BS70mrMkpUatOzrX29DihJu4BXBGHVQAFMGoZskWIggAlApG5GAAFsA0AHRwyAC8yMAxhuShEdHs8YlR7CnIgiSKALboAGIOIAhuAXo8jMGpxmAOUCDI4ZExyADUyADk-T3t6Tl5BcXoAHIQAO7VXjJyksQhyAD0a8gAQg71buwOYMh2RQAOwCIQkjCggZSK5MrNrYTIUe8dNAA0uv1wIOpwtAKAN+HlyBtkAB1MJwI4zcSJHAgVQQVT3VYbJ4tNogWZSWTiGhuAhvD7pH5UP4AoFQEH5AJjARCEiXI4IACMWTxMwJSxJVL6JRBPwsQvMfX4jOE9nUlyiInUjDcnKiJXKlWqjPWm1OPDAkgARMLYsL2IaWWzjgAmBaE+QJVUlaZzaUkSEAVUqcF2YSOABV0KcIABRKBQVzUBDWtVlCoIRKSGkUZAweNgYCaGUgGhyiAKpUqmPq+NamzuzYAEXUV2QyZO50uGMhgeD-VJVO4BmQFi71nyA0iyCKkRoTGGKBgcsVM3HevUwagGdrMAjRXaQZQfQw9pofWoJcqP2dszc1oA7ABmACcAVIVoQl7tSyypPeUU5lOofX+gLCwLgUFy0hABBERc2QDRa3rdQzguFA3BoOAihQaAIygO9WQgdkABZnyJV8yQ-LkwRZIA) for the code in this question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61741437/why-is-this-allowed-const-nums-number-1-2-3 _The type system doesn't have a way to mark interface members as "own" or enumerable, so the compiler assumes that all members are copied via the spread operator. As a heuristic, that's often adequate, but it does the wrong thing for any members set on a prototype, like methods of a class._

Comment: Thanks! That does look similar, but I don't see how its answer explains why in my example, TypeScript detects the error when it is made outside the class, but not when it is made inside.